# Using Entity Framework to retrieve distinct values from SQL Server in json for angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, json, entity-framework

I am having an issue where I'm trying to retrieve distinct values using Entity Framework and returning it in JSON format to use in an angularJS dropdown list.  When trying to retrieve distinct values I get the following error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collection.Generic.List to 'System.Collection.Generic.List'

Here is the code that causes an issue:

```html
            List<TABLE_NAME> objContext = new List<TABLE_NAME>();
            
            using (MyEntity dc = new MyEntity())
            {
                objContext = dc.TABLE_NAME.Where(a => a.COLUMN_NAME != null).Select(m >= m.COLUMN_NAME).Distinct().ToList();
            }
            return new JsonResult { Data = objContext, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
```

However this code runs without error but I don't get a list of distinct values:

```html
            List<TABLE_NAME> objContext = new List<TABLE_NAME>();
            
            using (MyEntity dc = new MyEntity())
            {
                objContext = dc.TABLE_NAME.OrderBy(a >= a.COLUMN_NAME).ToList();
            }
            return new JsonResult { Data = objContext, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
```

Thanks,

S

Comment: If you want return a list of strings (assuming `COLUMN_NAME` is of type `String`) your `objcontext` variable must be of type `List<String>` and you have to do the following: `dc.TABLE_NAME.WHERE(a => a.COLUMN_NAME != null).Select(m => m.COLUMN_NAME).Distinct().ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

U r specifying in select statement u only need a field data but u r trying to assign it into 
List

```
List<String> objContext = dc.TABLE_NAME.Where(a >= a.COLUMN_NAME != null).Select(m >= m.COLUMN_NAME).Distinct().ToList();
```

in this case

```
  objContext = dc.TABLE_NAME.OrderBy(a >= a.COLUMN_NAME).ToList();
```

This will not throw error because it return TABLE_NAME object so u can assign it to `List<TABLE_NAME>`

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply, I tried to change type to string and now I am getting a list of 'Undefined' in my dropdown.  I've changed code to:          public JsonResult GetDistinctColumnValues() {
           
            string objContext;;    
            using (MyEntity dc = new MyEntity())
            {
                objContext = dc.TABLE_NAME.WHERE(a => a.COLUMN_NAME != null).Select(m => m.COLUMN_NAME).Distinct().ToString();
            }
            return new JsonResult { Data = objContext, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }